# Change the color of input cell in jupyter in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am using VSCode with Jupyter (for .ipynb files) and I would like to change the color of my input cells.

Currently, it looks like this :
[image]

How can I change the color of my input cell without changing the theme I use ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings and mark `Python > Data Science: Ignore Vscode Theme`, then restart VScode, after which Notebooks will become white. Not beautiful, but at least you now can see the input cells without kissing the display:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Same as @tyrex answer, except that now it is under the "Jupyter" extension. Found it by searching for "vscode theme" in the settings.

Comment: Instead of posting an answer which merely links to another answer, please instead [flag the question](/help/privileges/flag-posts) as a duplicate.

Comment: Hi, I linked to an answer on the same question. I could not comment on the answer here because I still do not have enough reputation points. Would appreciate if you can tell me about another way to flag an answer possibly.